# PhalconPHP how to condition findFirst by join data

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, phalcon

I have two tables:

```
AuctionPackage
$this->belongsTo('id', 'AuctionPackageTranslation', 'auction_package_id', NULL);
```

and another one

```
AuctionPackageTranslation
$this->belongsTo('auction_package_id', 'AuctionPackage', 'id', NULL);
```

Now, when I do

```
$auction_order = AuctionOrder::findFirstByid($id);
```

I get all the correct data and in Volt I have access to the translation. But, I want to use findFirst instead of findFirstByid and do a condition, if one of the field in the joined language table has a ceratain value.

Like so:

```
    $auction_package = AuctionPackage::findFirst(array(
            "auction_package_translation.lang_id = '{$lang}'",
            "id = {$id}"
        ));
```

And I get error:

```
*Unknown model or alias 'auction_package_translation' (1), when preparing: SELECT [AuctionPackage].* FROM [AuctionPackage] WHERE auction_package_translation.lang_id = 'de' LIMIT ?1*
```

Does findFirst not join the tables and findFirstByid ? How can I condition something to joined table?

Answer (score 0):

Use relation name (class name) not table name. This is because PHQL uses class names when building query.

```
$auction_package = AuctionPackage::findFirst(array(
    "AuctionPackageTranslation.lang_id = '{$lang}'",
    "id = {$id}"
));
```